# how to add 5 minutes in current time?

Tags: iphone, nsdate

I am new in iPhone application development. I need to add 5 minutes in current time. example format current time is "6:15:00" means i want to add 5 minutes like this result "6:20:00" can you help me.

Thanks

Comment: Can you show how you get the current time?  I don't really know Objective-C, but in Java and C# the time classes have methods that allow you to add time to a time value.  Please show what you have so far.

Comment: possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2329272/how-to-add-a-time-interval-to-an-nsdate?rq=1

Answer (score 3, accepted):

See [NSDate class reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSDate_Class/Reference/Reference.html):

```
NSDate* newDate = [oldDate dateByAddingTimeInterval:60.0*5];
```

Answer (score 2):

```
NSDate *nowPlus5Min = [NSDate dateWithTimeIntervalSinceNow:5*60];
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do this by adding seconds in the time using this code..this will add 300 second in current date....you can change time according to your requirement

```
NSDate *dateToFire = [[NSDate date] dateByAddingTimeInterval:5*60];
```